# Setting up emacs/slime/swank for clojure with leiningen

Tags: emacs, clojure, slime, swank, leiningen

Short version: errors when running M-x slime-connect or M-x clojure-jack-in when using lein swank to start the swank server.

I'm using emacs 24.0.50.1 on Ubuntu 10.10. I've installed the following packages in emacs from ELPA: clojure-mode, paredit, slime, slime-repl

I installed leiningen from github & added it to the classpath, then ran 
`lein plugin install swank-clojure 1.3.3`. 
After that I created a new directory ~/tmp/, cd into it and ran:
`lein new test-project` which seemed to setup everything ok. Then I opened up /tmp/new-project/project.clj in emacs and changed it to:

```
(defproject test-project "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
:description "Test Project"
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.2.1"]
               [org.clojure/clojure-contrib "1.2.0"]]
:dev-dependencies [[swank-clojure "1.3.3"]])
```

After that I went back in the /tmp/new-project folder and ran `lein deps` then `lein swank` to download the dependencies and start the swank server which gives the output:

```
Connection opened on local port 4005.
```

Back in emacs is where I'm having the problem of getting it to connect to the swank server. I've tried opening the core.clj file and running `M-x slime-connect` which gives the error:

```
Symbol's function definition is void: define-slime-contrib
```

Which makes me think it either doesn't see the swank server running or there's some config that needs to be done for it to see the server. I also tried (with the same file open and with project.clj open) `M-x clojure-jack-in`which I assume tries to start the clojure REPL in the project folder but that gives the following:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Could not start swank server: sh: lein: not found
")
signal(error ("Could not start swank server: sh: lein: not found\n"))
error("Could not start swank server: %s" "sh: lein: not found\n")
clojure-jack-in-sentinel(#<process swank> "exited abnormally with code 127\n")
```

I was following directions from http://matthias-schneider.org/docs/clojure-setup/ for the emacs packages and lein setup, then started following the Test Configuration instructions from http://riddell.us/ClojureSwankLeiningenWithEmacsOnLinux.html once I had problems getting M-x slime-connect to open a REPL.

**Update**:

deleted ~/tmp/test-project, uninstalled emacs and /.emacs.d/elpa/ packages, reinstalled emacs, reinstalled clojure-mode and paredit packages, copied ~/.lein into /bin to make sure of no path issues (wasn't sure if /.lein or /.lein/bin needed to be in the path). Ran `/.lein/bin/swank-clojure` and then opened emacs, opened the project.clj, and tried `M-x slime-connect`, which now asks me for a host (local default), port (4005 default), says connecting to swank, gives a message about swank and slime versions differing (y or n) y, then the minibuffers gives `error in process filter: Lisp connection closed unexpectedly`. In the terminal where I ran `/.lein/bin/swank-clojure` the following java error pops up:

```
exception in read loop
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "    a6"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:470)
at swank.core.protocol$read_swank_message.invoke(protocol.clj:41)
at swank.core.connection$read_from_connection.invoke(connection.clj:59)
at swank.core$read_loop.invoke(core.clj:337)
at swank.swank$connection_serve$fn__1486$fn__1487.invoke(swank.clj:32)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper(AFn.java:159)
at clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo(AFn.java:151)
at clojure.core$apply.invoke(core.clj:540)
at swank.swank$connection_serve$fn__1486.doInvoke(swank.clj:29)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:397)
at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

**Update:**
Solved, I needed to uninstall emacs and delete ALL of /.emacs.d/, not just the packages in /elpa/. After reinstalling I only got clojure-mode package, not slime or slime-repl. Can now connect with `M-x clojure-jack-in` and am ready to do some work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to install slime and slime-repl: they are embedded into lein's plugin (see inside the jar: swank-clojure-1.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar\swank\payload). You have to install just the clojure-mode.

Also, when "reinstalling", remember to delete also the hidden folder .emacs.d in your $HOME directory, otherwise it will keep your previously downloaded Emacs plugins.

Finally prefer clojure-jack-in, not slime-connect - just having slime-connect means that you are still having a SLIME inside Emacs, so you didn't remove it.

Comment: Thanks! That did it. I dumped /.emacs.d/ and reinstalled again (before I just deleted the folders in /.emacs.d/elpa/). Then I only reinstalled the clojure-mode package. Now works with `M-x clojure-jack-in`. I guess it had something to do with the slime or slime-repl packages I was downloading. Also still using swank-clojure 1.3.3 and it's working without slime packages so I will avoid 1.4.0-SNAPSHOT unless something else pops up.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a beginner's guide for setting up Emacs + nREPL client with auto-complete and documentation popup since most old instructions weren't appropriate. Available [here](http://blog.worldcognition.com/2012/07/setting-up-emacs-for-clojure-programming.html). May be helpful for newcomers.

Comment: Tutorial updated to use nrepl.el in favor of SLIME and swank-clojure.

Answer (score 1):

No need to install lein swank plugin. You can add the dependencies in the project.clj file and just `lein swank` & `M-x slime-connect`.

Try with swank-clojure "1.2.1", it works for me.

Comment: Changed to "1.2.1" in project.clj, ran `lein deps`, ls shows "1.2.1" in lib/dev/, `lein swank`, & `M-x slime-connect` gives the same error. Thanks for trying though I was just going with newer versions since I wasn't sure if emacs 24 would have problems with older versions.

Comment: Un install the plugin & try again.. You can refer the Known issues are in swank-clojure github account: https://github.com/technomancy/swank-clojure

Comment: Uninstalled the plugin with `lein plugin uninstall swank-clojure 1.3.3` (~/.lein/plugins is empty now), ran `lein deps` & `lein swank` in the project folder, `M-x slime-connect` and `M-x clojure-jack-in` still give the same errors. Something I noticed now is when running lein swank it gives:
    `user=> Connection opened on local port  4005
    #<ServerSocket ServerSocket[addr=localhost/127.0.0.1,port=0,localport=4005]>`

instead of the single line in the original post

Comment: @element8 : Correct! do M-x slime-connect after you get the above message!

Comment: I did, but it still gives the same error messages in the original post. Do you think it might be something with the packages I downloaded from ELPA?

Comment: So, uninstall the emacs and other packages, I don't recommend installing the package through the lein plugin. Install manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the following, which works for me with Emacs 24 on Ubuntu:

1. Install Leiningen. Make sure the directory where you install `lein` is on the `$PATH`!
2. Install swank-clojure plugin:

   `lein plugin install swank-clojure 1.3.3`
3. Create a new project with `lein new`. Do not add `swank-clojure`to the `:dev-dependencies`. (You really only need one or the other, the plugin or the entry in `:dev-dependencies`.)
4. Start Emacs, making sure it can "see" `lein` on the `$PATH`, e.g. like this:

   `PATH=$PATH:/path-to/dir-where/lein-is emacs`

   (Use this command to try it out. For permanent use you should update the `$PATH` in your `.profile` file or install `lein` in a location that's already on the `$PATH`. In a standard Ubuntu install, `~/bin` should be on the `$PATH`.)
5. Open a file from the project, e.g. `project.clj`, and run `M-x clojure-jack-in`. This should start the Swank server and connect the SLIME REPL to it.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm closer but still not quite there. I followed your directions and started emacs with `PATH=$PATH:/home/element8/.lein emacs-snapshot`. Once in emacs I opened project.clj in /tmp/test-project, and tried `M-x clojure-jack-in` which gives in the minibuffer: `starting swank...` then `Loading ` something quick, I couldn't read it all but it looked like slime in /.emacs.d/, then gives the same error `Symbol's function definition is void: define-slime-contrib`

Comment: I also tried copying ~/.lein into /bin and it gives the same error as above, think I'm going to try reinstalling emacs and get the packages again to make sure that isn't the problem.

Comment: reinstalled emacs, reinstalled the 4 packages i had(clojure-mode, slime, slime-repl, and paredit), there were some warnings when the packages compiled but they compiled, and running `M-x clojure-jack-in` with project.clj open gives the following messages: `Starting swank server... Loading /home/element8/.emacs.d/swank/slime-c3230b2c.elc... error in process filter: eval-buffer: Symbol's function definition is void: define-slime-contrib error in process filter: Symbol's function definition is void: define-slime-contrib` I think my problem is with the slime package in .emacs.d but I'm not sure.

Comment: looks like I was wrong, removed the slime and slime-repl packages from emacs and the same error occurs, looks like it's coming from /.emacs.d/swank/ which I think it's pulling from swank-clojure 1.3.3 installed in lein.

Answer (score 0):

this happened to me when i cloned someone else's clojure project from an older version. their project.clj had:

```
:dev-dependencies [[lein-clojars "0.5.0"]
                   [swank-clojure "1.2.1"]]
```

which is incorrect, i think, if you're using `M-x clojure-jack-in`. removing these lines, running `lein deps` and jacking in worked for me.